# NLP Flask app startup nodes timing out on Google Kubernetes GKE

Tags: flask, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I have a flask app that includes some NLP packages and takes a while to initially build some vectors before it starts the server. I've noticed this in the past with Google App Engine and I was able to set a max timeout in the app.yaml file to fix this.

The problem is that when I start my cluster on Kubernetes with this app, I notice that the workers keep timing out in the logs. Which makes sense because I'm sure the default amount of time is not enough. However, I can't figure out how to configure GKE to allow the workers enough time to do everything it needs to do before it starts serving.

How do I increase the time the workers can take before they timeout?

I deleted the old instances so I can't get the logs right now, but I can start it up if someone wants to see the logs.

It's something like this:

```
I 2020-06-26T01:16:04.603060653Z Computing vectors for all products
E 2020-06-26T01:16:05.660331982Z 
95it [00:05, 17.84it/s][2020-06-26 01:16:05 +0000] [220] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 220
E 2020-06-26T01:16:31.198002748Z [nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to /root/nltk_data...
E 2020-06-26T01:16:31.198056691Z [nltk_data]   Package stopwords is already up-to-date!
100it 2020-06-26T01:16:35.696015992Z [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:220)
E 2020-06-26T01:16:35.696015992Z [2020-06-26 01:16:35 +0000] [220] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 220)
```

I also see this:

```
The node was low on resource: memory. Container thoughtful-sha256-1 was using 1035416Ki, which exceeds its request of 0.
```

Obviously I don't exactly know what I'm doing. Why does it say I'm requesting 0 memory and can I set a timeout amount for the Kubernetes nodes?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is add some sort of delay in a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) for your GCP instances. You could try a simple:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

sleep <time-in-seconds>
```

Another thing you can try is adding some sort of delay to when your containers start in your Kubernetes nodes. For example, a delay in an [initContainer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/)

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp-container
    image: myapa:latest
  initContainers:
  - name: init-myservice
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', "echo Waiting a bit && sleep 3600"]
```

Furthermore, you can try a [StartupProbe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) combined with the [Probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes) parameter `initialDelaySeconds` on your actual application container that way it actually waits for some time before saying: *I'm going to see if the application has started*.:

```yaml
startupProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - touch
    - /tmp/started
  initialDelaySeconds: 3600
```

Comment: thanks so much Rico for the advice. Unfortunately, I think I have a different problem than the one I thought I actually had. I am running my app directly on compute engine, and it seems to work better, but now it also seems to fail silently. Anyway, thanks!